# Can anyone please explain how to perform the $and filter rest api query with strapi v4? I am new to Strapi. THANKS

Tags: filtering, strapi

Can anyone please explain how to perform the $and filter rest api query with strapi v4? I am new to strapi and followed the guidance in the documentation but this does not work. Thanks alot!

An example of what I am trying to do:

Retrieve a list of students who are enrolled in both Maths and Physics. I appreciate any help that is offered!

Answer (score 0):

```
api/students?filters[$and][0][classes][subject][$eq]=Maths&filters[$and][1][classes][subject][$eq]=Physics
```

You may try this one, assuming 1 student has N classes, which there is subject field in class